# Nginx Rewrite to Previous Directory

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, rewrite, wordpress

I am trying to move my blog from **blog.example.com** to **example.com/blog** to do this I would rather not move anything on disk, so instead i changed my nginx configuration file to the following:

```
location /blog {
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}
    root /home/demo/public_html/blog.example.com/current/public/;
    index  index.php index.html index.html;
        passenger_enabled off;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @blog;
}
```

This works great but when i visit example.com/blog nginx looks for:

```
/home/demo/public_html/blog.example.com/current/public/blog/index.php
```

instead of

```
/home/demo/public_html/blog.example.com/current/public/index.php
```

Is there a way to put in a rewrite rule so that I can have the server automatically take out the /blog/ directory?

something like ?

```
location /blog {
        rewrite \\blog\D  \;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood the usage of root. What you really want is the alias directive: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#alias

Comment: thanks so much for answering, i was beginning to get a little lonely here ^_^

Comment: When I change root to alias i get error "No input file specified." when i visit the page and no errors in my error.log

Comment: This has to do with your SCRIPT_FILENAME fastcgi param value.

Comment: I ended up being able to use a symlink to the correct directory.